# @InitBinder using command object in property editors…

Tags: spring, spring-3

I'm migrating an app from Spring 2.0.7 to 3.1.1 and I struck a problem with initBinder. We used to have methods looking like

```
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    MyCommand command = (MyCommand)binder.getTarget();
    binder.registerCustomEditor(CustomerCard.class, createEditorFromCommand(command));
}
```

where the target is used by the PropertyEditor. This method is no longer called when I made it an annotated Controller so I added the `@InitBinder` annotation:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    MyCommand command = (MyCommand)binder.getTarget();
    binder.registerCustomEditor(CustomerCard.class, createEditorFromCommand(command));
}
```

Unfortunately the `binder.getTarget()` is just some default object. The documentation for @InitBinder also states that I can't get the command as a parameter either:

> Such init-binder methods support all arguments that {@link
>   RequestMapping} supports, except for command/form objects and
>   corresponding validation result objects.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  MyCommand command = (MyCommand)binder.getTarget();
  binder.registerCustomEditor(CustomerCard.class, createEditorFromCommand(command));
}
```

Comment: That code gives the same problem. The command is just an `Object` and not my registered command.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping
// binder will return MyCommand on getTarget()
public void handleMyCommand(MyCommand c) {  
 ...
}

// initialize command before handleMyCommand method call
@ModelAttribute
public MyCommand initializeMyCommand() {
   // perform initialization.
}

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
   MyCommand c  = (MyCommand) binder.getTarget();
   binder.registerCustomEditor(CustomerCard.class, createEditorFromCommand(c));
}
```

But, as command is unitialized ¿Why you don't call to `createEditorFromCommand(new MyCommand())` directly?

Comment: The command shouldn't be uninitialized, that's the thing. I think my problem is that I'm combining old Spring class hierarchies with annotations. I'm kind of in between right now, trying to move to the new way one controller at a time. I have an old `formBackingObject`, but since this one isn't called by Spring anymore I made a new method with `@ModelAttribute` that then calls this old `formBackingObject`. However, `@ModelAttribute` doesn't do anything with the command object I return from the method, is that correct? Is there any other way to have "register" the command?

Comment: To initialize commands, use @ModelAttribute on methods. I just edit answer with example.

Comment: I did that. It seems the problem is that `initBinder` is called more than once. Beside a `@ModelAttribute` method like the one above, I also have void-returning one that takes a model map and sets a whole lot of stuff in it. It seems the initBinder is called for everything. I got it working with doing an instanceof-check in on the target, but it seems hacky…?

Comment: Yes initBinder will be called every time that a bind process on a command start, so a handler like handle(Command1 c1, Command2 c2) will call initBinder twice. PropertyEditors convert instance classes from/to text. I think that is not exptected that you choose PEs based on instance data, ¿May be better to do an unique PE for CustomCard that can handle all posibilities and simply register them on the initBinder method?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late to the party, but still - here is a way to reference model (command) object in @InitBinder method:

```
@InitBinder("commandName")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
   CommandClass command = (CommandClass) binder.getTarget();
   binder.registerCustomEditor(Some.class, new SomeEditor(command.getOptions());
}

@ModelAttribute("commandName")
public OrderItem createCommand(HttpServletRequest request) {
   return new CommandClass();
}
```

It may be a good idea to put @InitBinder("something") instead of just @InitBinder. This way @InitBinder won't be called multiple times, but rather only called when configured object is encountered.